# Spring Test context scope

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-test

I am new in Spring test, and I have ran a lot of unit test successfully according to the documents step by step,however I have some questions:

**1 Can all the TestCase use a global Spring Context**

Now I configure each TeseCase the spring context like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(.....)
@Transactional
public class UserDaoTests {} 


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(.....)
@Transactional
public class AccoutDaoTests {}
```

As shown, spring will load and destroy the same context again and again.

So I wonder if I can setup a global Spring context, and then make all the TestCases run inside this context?

**2 Transaction management**

It said that the Transaction Manager will rollback the operations to the database.

But I have not found in which case this feature will work.

Because in my application I use ORMLite instead of Spring JDBC.

And this is the configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
<!-- our daos -->
<bean id="ormliteSource" class="com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionSource" init-method="initialize">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userDao" class="com.j256.ormlite.spring.DaoFactory" factory-method="createDao">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="ormliteSource"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="com.springapp.model.User"/>
</bean>
```

And then in my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(..)
@Transactional
public class UserDaoTests {
    @Autowired
    private Dao<User, Long> userDao;

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        User u = new User();
        u.setName("ysl");
        u.setLocked(true);
        try {
            userDao.create(u);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I run the test, and I found that all the tests are successfully passed, but when I check the database, I found that there are some test data inserted, it seems that the rollback does not work.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: This are two distinct questions in the same post. This makes answering the questions harder. Please post the questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

Spring should detect if it can setup a shared application context for you. Did you specify different xmls in different test cases? If your test case could run against a shared application context, you may try with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(.....)
public abstract class AbstractSpringTests

public class ConcreteTests1 extends AbstractSpringTests

public class ConcreteTests2 extends AbstractSpringTests
```

In this case, spring should setup only one application context.

According to the reference, you should add @TransactionConfiguration instead of @Transactinal on test class(rollback is the default strategy if I'm not mistaken)

> If you want a transaction to commit — unusual, but occasionally useful when you want a particular
>   test to populate or modify the database — the TestContext framework can be instructed to cause the
>   transaction to commit instead of roll back via the @TransactionConfiguration and @Rollback
>   annotations.